# Can an angular function be partially async?

Tags: angular

I currently have a method as below:

```
async doCreateProduct(){

if(!canProceed){
  throw new Error("Cannot Proceed");
}

// this.create product calls api to return an id
var generatedId = await lastValueFrom(this.createProduct());

if(generatedId != null){
  // do other actions
}
}
```

My problem is - I had to make the method async only because it needs to wait to get generatedId from createProduct in order to decide if it will do other actions.

Is it a good approach? As I believe the function would be expecting to return a Promise. So the throw new Error part does not actually feel right.

My unit test also fails to get the error: Unhandled Promise rejection:

```
describe('When cannot proceed', () => {
 it('should throw error', () => {
 expect(() => service.doCreateProduct()).toThrowError();
 });
 });
```

Any idea of what I am doing wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, it will only return promise when `doCreateProduct` is true;

```
function hello (doCreateProduct = true) {
        if (!doCreateProduct) {
            return false;
        } else {
        return new Promise(async (res, rej) => {
               const generatedId = await lastValueFrom(this.createProduct()); 
                res(generatedId);
        })
        }
}
```